# Angular - Cannot destructure property 'country' of '(intermediate value)' as it is null

Tags: angular

I created the Angular project from scratch. I'm running the default project/application that is created when the project is created (ie it's empty). Next, I open the console and see: “Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'country' of '(intermediate value)' as it is null. at proxyOverlay.js:1:6311".

This has never happened before.

Now I don't know how to get rid of this.

Please tell me how to solve this problem?

```
    Angular CLI: 17.0.10
    Node: 20.11.0
    Package Manager: npm 10.2.4
    OS: win32 x64
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnVst.png)

Comment: plz check the node version, angular only certain versions of node are compatible e.g. node 18

Comment: @Naren Murali I had version 18. As soon as this error appeared, I updated to version 20 thinking that the error would disappear, but the error remained.

Comment: An error like this has never appeared. Yesterday I launched the project and this error appeared.

Comment: I just did this on a virtual clean machine. The problem is not observed. On the main machine where the problem appears, I cleared the cache and cookies - it didn't help.

Comment: I think that the problem should be closed.. The problem is in the Chrome browser.

Comment: Of course, I would like to know exactly why this happens.

Comment: seems to be not an angular issue, hope you solve it!

Comment: I am having same issue on chrome browser console, but I have tried on edge browser, its working perfectly fine. I guess @NarenMurali is right, it does not seem to be an angular issue.

Answer (score 5):

You might have a vpn extension running in the browser. Turn it of

Comment: why does that happen, when we use VPN ? can you explain more about this error

Answer (score 3):

У меня такую ошибку выдает расширение для chrome - Browsec VPN. Ошибка выходит даже когда VPN выключен. Если отключить его в настройках chrome://extensions/ то ошибка пропадет

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Привет Антон--Q & A on Stack Overflow should be in English. SO на русском is at https://ru.stackoverflow.com 

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I resolved it by removing the VPN extension from the browser!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

its the vpn extention click mange extention and make Allow this extension to read and change all your data on websites you visit:on click

Answer (score 0):

As was written above in Ru, the Browsec VPN extension in Chrome cause this error in console. Even if the extension not turned on, but just installed.